# Why is the instance reloaded when using immutable deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops

I'm trying to set up version upgrade in AWS EBS with Deployment policy "immutable deployment". Everything works, normally, except for one moment. Immediately after deleting the "old" auto-scalling group, the "new" instance is replaced once again. With what it can be connected and where it is worth paying attention?

[image: Screen Logs]

Comment: For me it's seems ok. I don't see duplicate replication

Comment: Maybe, but it's strange, when the update ends, the instance restarts again. This is the essence of the question, why does he do an additional restart and whether it can be removed